# Different versions of database and SQL Server; Couldn't find SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm currently working on ASP.NET MVC project with my partner and we are using TFS. We both were using VS 2013, but then I reinstalled my OS and have installed VS 2015 Community. When I downloaded the project from TFS almost everything went fine, I can run the website, but when the website needs access to database (when logging in...), the exception occures. SQL server express 2014 has been installed on the pc, so problem is probably in different versions of database and SQL Server or in connection string. But how can I fix this?

Second screen says: `When creating connection to server an error has occured. Server was not found or was not accessible. Check if the name of an instance is correct and if the server is configured to allow remote access.`

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

Connection string in web config looks like this:  `<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Dobrokarty-20141117025208.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Dobrokarty-20141117025208;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: Which connection string are you using?

Comment: I added the connection string. See edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you installed SQL Server 2014 Express, you should use "(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB" as Data Source.

Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Your Connection string should then look like:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Dobrokarty-20141117025208.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Dobrokarty-20141117025208;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```